# TinyMce replacing <a name="location"> tag with &nbsp;

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMce version 6 in my site. I have a text editor with the "code" plugin which allow my users to edit the html of their content. However, any time my users add the following code:

```
<a name="location"></a>
```

it is saved as:

```
&nbsp;
```

but this is only happening with the name="location" and location="forms", it is not happening with any other name so I'm not sure if there is a list of reserved keywords for it.